# How do I update golang standard library in my go application?

Tags: go, security, package, dependencies, vendoring

I have an application that was built with `go` 1.16.4, which uses (imports) the `archive/zip` component of the Go std lib. I took a look at the [golang Release Notes](https://golang.org/doc/devel/release#go1.16) and see that a security vulnerability has been fixed in `archive/zip` in golang 1.16.5. How do I ensure that my application is no longer vulnerable? Must I upgrade my version of `go` itself, and then rebuild with that new version of `go`? Or could I vendor the newer version of the fixed component then rebuild? Must the files in the build machine's `$GOROOT` be updated?

Comment: Update your Go tool, then rebuild the app. Easiest, safest, simplest.

Comment: The standard library is a part of Go; you cannot specify a version, nor can you vendor it. Just update Go and rebuild.

Comment: If binary is built with docker (a good solution to make repeatable builds, instead of a local environment), it is as simple as changing the version of the image to 1.16.5 and recompile.

Comment: Forget about GOROOT you wont need it (ever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Must I upgrade my version of `go` itself, and then rebuild with that new version of `go`?

Yes...

1. Upgrade Go.
2. Rebuild.

> Or could I vendor the newer version of the fixed component then rebuild?

No, you can't vendor the Go standard library.

> Must the files in the build machine's `$GOROOT` be updated?

GOROOT is the root folder of the Go SDK installation. It is updated when you upgrade Go on the machine (or container) that invokes `go build`/`go install`.